# play video with subtitles

Tags: javascript, video, mobile-safari, html5-video

Hi i want to see a video with a subtitle ".srt" in html5.
What can i do with javascript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first results in Google; query: "html5 video subtitles" (there's lots of materials):

- http://blog.gingertech.net/2008/12/12/attaching-subtitles-to-html5-video/
- http://www.bluishcoder.co.nz/2008/12/srt-subtitles-with-html5-video.html

If you are using jQuery, choosing jQuery.srt seems good.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to add this, to the list above.

http://bubbles.childnodes.com/

Supported, youtubelike annotations, multiple-languages, subtitle synchronization, tracking and much more.